# Source that a mourner in his year does not lead the selichos in Elul and Tishrei?

Tags: mourning-aveilus, chazzan-prayer-leader, selichot

I have been told that there is a Mishna Berurah that states that a mourner should not lead the selichos but can take over leading the prayers for shacharis.

Please locate this Mishna Berurah.

Comment: Is the claim that a mourner ought not to lead selichot due to his status as a mourner, or that his status as a mourner does not give him any sort of precedence in being selected to lead, as it would do for the regular prayers?

Comment: I understand it to be the first " that a mourner ought not to lead selichot due to his status as a mourner".

Comment: In that case there's a Mishnah Berurah which says the exact opposite - 581:7

Comment: Right! I will ask the person who told me. Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: There are those who do bring down such a custom, just not the MB (as far as I can tell) https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=419

Comment: "can take over leading the prayers for shacharis" There is a custom that the slichos leader specifically leads shacharis that day too even if he isn't a mourner.

Comment: @joelk the Mishna berura you mention is referring to the regular tefillos on the days of selichos, not selichos themselves.

Comment: That's right - now I read it carefully.

Comment: @Chatzkel MB brings down later that the one who leads selichot continues the rest of the prayers, and has precedence over a mourner. If a mourner is leading shacharit, presumably he led selichot as well.